# How to setup PWA on Magento2 for production environment?

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

I have setup PWA Studio on Magento 2.3.7.

When I run `Yarn Build` build generates successfully.

After that `Yarn watch:venia` also executed with custom URL like below

[image]

But when I change Staging server URL from .env file with website domain name, and executing `yarn stage:venia` it throws me below error.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to figure out what steps I need to follow to run PWA storefront on specific domain on server?

Answer (score 0):

run `npm start`

it will generate the custom URL and port

add the domain and port in your virtual host configurations

install pm2 on your server

add your venia app pm2

in this way to you run venia on prodcution